# Showing AWS Lex Responce cards on chatbot integrated to website

Tags: chatbot, amazon-lex

I have created a chatbot in AWS Lex and integrated it with my website. After that, I used AWS Lex Response Cards on my chatbot and those response cards are not working in my chatbot integrated into my website. I have integrated the same bot in Facebook page there response cards are working fine.
How to display response cards onto my website's chatbot?

Answer (score 1):

The Chatbot client is responsible for rendering and showing the responses and response cards to the user. Facebook (client) is able to render the response cards sent by Lex.
You could do below:

- In your website you should write some logic to render the response
  card and convert the JSON into HTML
- Instead of sending the response card, send the HTML code from Lambda
  function which you want to show on website

Hope it helps.

Comment: Can I have any examples of your first suggestion.Converting JSON to HTML.I am facing a similar issue.